# Countdown timer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, ajax

How do you make a Countdown timer?

When the user loads the page, clock starts counting down, it reaches time, it redirects browser to a new page.

Found this, it was not too useful.
http://encosia.com/2007/07/25/display-data-updates-in-real-time-with-ajax/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this?

```
   <div id="countDiv"></div>

    <script>
    function countDown (count) {
      if (count > 0) {
       var d = document.getElementById("countDiv");
       d.innerHTML = count;
       setTimeout (function() { countDown(count-1); }, 1000);
       }
      else
       document.location = "someotherpage.html";
    }
    countDown(5);
    </script>
```

Comment: For the many who may end up reading this thread... You don't want to pass a string to setTimeout. Instead pass it an anonymous function:
`setTimeout(function() { countDown(count-1); }, 1000);`

Comment: @rob: Consider editing your answer to improve it as per RobFlaherty's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to use the [Timer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

with pure javascript you could do it like this

```
window.onload=function(){ // makes sure the dom is ready
  setTimeout('function(){document.location = "http://www.google.com"}', 10000) // redirects you to google after 10 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
    When this counter reaches 0, you will be redirected to
    <a href="http://path.to.wherever/" id="redirectme">wherever</a>.
    <span id="counter">10</span>
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(){

    var
        counter = document.getElementById("counter"),
        count = parseInt(counter.innerHTML),
        url = document.getElementById("redirectme").href,
        timer;

    function countdown() {
        count -= 1;
        counter.innerHTML = count;
        if (count <= 0) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            window.location.assign(url);
        }
    }

    timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000); // 1000 ms

})();
</script>
```