# jQuery show setTimeout timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, settimeout

I'm trying to build a simple countdown application. Is it possible to show the timer value on setTimeout, or would I have to use a for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: `setTimeout` is the way to go. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835087/countdown-timer

Comment: How can I display the timer value, though?

Comment: @Rocketeer: Are you asking how to display the current time? Please be more specific?

Comment: You'd set the content of an element to current countdown value.

Comment: Yeah, current time remaining on the timer. I would have to use some variant of increment function?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

with `setTimeout` :

```
var n = 100;
setTimeout(countDown,1000);

function countDown(){
   n--;
   if(n > 0){
      setTimeout(countDown,1000);
   }
   console.log(n);
}
```

or using `setInterval` :

```
var n = 100;
var tm = setInterval(countDown,1000);

function countDown(){
   n--;
   if(n == 0){
      clearInterval(tm);
   }
   console.log(n);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be possible with setTimeout also?

Comment: setInterval is more reliable because it will fire every second regardless of how much time it takes to process the function. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval

Comment: please take that alert out, it hurts !

Comment: @mgraph, I believe you forgot add return statement in if right after `setTimeout(countDown,1000);` for setTImeout variant

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
var timer = setInterval("mytimer()",1000);
seconds = 0;
function mytimer()
{
document.getElementById("div_timer").innerHTML = seconds; // this is the same as $("div_timer").html(timer) in       jquery.
seconds++;
} 

 </script>
    <body>
      <div id="div_timer"></div>
       </body>
```