# Prevent sending duplicate data using GET

Tags: google-apps-script

I built a custom form which sends all its data to Google Spreadsheet via a simple Google Script using GET method.
After submitting the form, I show a Thank You page which is hosted on GS and called via HtmlService. 
This page's URL has all the values of the form, and if I refresh the Thank You page, I get duplicate data on my spreadsheet, which is a disaster.

I tried different methods of setting a timer to redirect to a different page after 5 seconds with no success. Something is blocking my script. (I know that it's working because I can show an alert, but not redirect the page automatically).

Is there any option to prevent duplicate data to be sent to the spreadsheet? I don't care if it's setting a timeout to the Thank You page (which SHOULD be relatively easy), or using a unique token for each submit.

Thanks.

Comment: So, all the form data is being sent to the "Thank You" page?  Does the "Thank You" page have a form in it?

Comment: All the data is sent to the spreadsheet via GET. The Thank You page is just a simple HTML with "Thanks for submitting!. Go back-->"

Comment: Can you show the code that opens up the "Thank You" page?

Comment: I have an html file called ThankYou.html on gs, and I pass it one of the values (it's the last example on documentation of gs): ˋvar ty = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ThankYou');
  ty.lv = lastValue; 
  return ty.evaluate();ˋ

Comment: It would be even better for me to have the Thank You page automatically redirect to another page after 5 seconds. That'd be as good as killing two birds with one stone. Any ideas how?

Comment: You can have a time driven project trigger that runs, but I think that the smallest time for that is one minute.  You probably want something that redirects after a few seconds.

Comment: If you want a countdown timer, take a look at this post:

[StackOverflow Countdown Timer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835087/countdown-timer

Comment: Is the custom form also in gas?

Comment: @ZigMandel  No, it's useless...

Comment: still not clear if the custom form is or isnt written on Apps script. either (1) both the form and the backend are in apps script or (2) you have a form on a "regular" html page not hosted with apps script, and redirect to an apps script page. Each have a very different answer and in both its possible to do what you want.

Comment: @ZigMandel The form is a regular HTML file hosted on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem is that you have a html page that submits data to gas by having the user click a link or redirect. Instead you need to call gas with ajax get, and your html (not gas) shows the thank you page.

Comment: Thanks, I did not consider that option. It requires me to change some parts of the code, so I'll see if other options work for me first, and if they don't, then this is a 100% solution.

Answer (score 0):

Data like that should be sent with a POST, not a GET.

Try using doPost(e) instead of doGet() in your published script and post the data to it.

Comment: Do you know where there is any documentation on `doPost()`? In the [HtmlService Forms](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) section, the example uses `google.script.run` to pass info to the server - a perfect place to use a `POST`.

Comment: I tried switching to doPost(e), and method="post" on ˋ<form>ˋ,  however, refreshing Thank You page still creates duplicate data.

Comment: Post or get makes no difference in this case

Answer (score 0):

If refreshing the "Thank You" page is sending data to your spreadsheet again, and the Thank You

> page's URL has all the values of the form

, then somehow you have combined the GET request and the serving of the Thank You page.  That needs to be separated out.  You need to serve the Thank You page without putting the values of the form in the URL.  Even if the Thank You page doesn't have any of the data in it, and doesn't have a form in it, if the URL is triggering another request, then the data is going to be sent all over again.

Comment: This is my Thank You page: ˋ   <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="content">
        Thank You, <?= lv; ?>!
        </div>
        
        <div class="goBack">
        <a href="link" target="_self" id="goBackLink">Go Back</a>
        </div>ˋ

Comment: Ok, you want the page to navigate back in the same window.  `taget="_self"` is the default, so I don't think that is needed. You have a scriptlet of `<?= lv; ?>!`.  I think that line is totally wrong.  It should look something like:  `<?!= lv(); ?>`, where `lv` is the name of a `.gs` code function.  If you have the exclamation point at the end, that's wrong.  Use something like Firebug or Google developer tools to look at the browsers console window for error messages.  Improperly formatted HTML could be causing a problem.  In Chrome, look for Tools, Developer Tools, then the console window.

Comment: That's a variable I passed down from the .gs script, and it's working just fine. You can take a look at the documentation on Google